# How do I capture system audio output on Windows?

Tags: rust, audio

I am trying to capture system audio (like the sound output from YouTube videos or Google Meet calls) on Windows using Rust. My goal is to capture the audio that is being played on the system and process it (initially just print the raw data to the console).

**Using windows-rs**
I am using the windows-rs crate to interface with the Windows Core Audio API. Here's a snippet of what I've tried:

```
unsafe {
    let audio_client: IAudioClient = device.Activate(IAudioClient::IID, CLSCTX_ALL, std::ptr::null_mut())?;
    let wave_format = audio_client.GetMixFormat()?;
    audio_client.Initialize(AUDCLNT_SHAREMODE_SHARED, AUDCLNT_STREAMFLAGS_LOOPBACK, 0, 0, wave_format, None)?;

    // Starting the client and setting up the capture client...
    let capture_client: IAudioCaptureClient = audio_client.GetService()?;

    loop {
        // Handling the audio buffer and processing...
        let mut data_ptr: *mut u8;
        let mut num_frames_available: u32;
        // ... calling GetBuffer() ...
    }
}
```

However, I ran into several issues with the windows-rs approach, particularly with the correct usage of COM interfaces and methods like GetBuffer(also there isn't much documentation on this topic).

For the windows-rs approach, am I missing something crucial in how to correctly use the Core Audio API in Rust?

Comment: what are the issues you are running into?